# How can I display background notification in flutter sent from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

even I followed the instructions and I can print the response of the notification in console but I cannot display the notification on the screen of the device
here is my code in main.dart file

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.data}");
}

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
  importance: Importance.max,
);
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.android,
  );

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("newService");

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print('for');
    RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;

    // If `onMessage` is triggered with a notification, construct our own
    // local notification to show to users using the created channel.
    if (notification != null) {
      // && android != null) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              channel.description,
            ),
          ));
    }
  });
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      .createNotificationChannel(channel);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I followed firebase messaging instructions

Answer (score 0):

Use this class to manage your notification service with firebase messaging

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class NotificationService {
  static Future<void> init() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
      await messaging.requestPermission();
    }

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    });


    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  }

  static Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
      RemoteMessage message) async {
    
  }
}
```

In the onMessage case, that means what will happen when a notification comes and your app is opened
In onBackgroundCase, that means what will happen when notifications come in background

If you need to show something while app is opened on notifications
put any methods that call widgets

Some notes:

1. You have to initialize firebase in on 'main.dart'

- Add this to void main method

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

2. convert your widget that has material app widget to stateful widget and put this line on the init state
   ex:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    NotificationService.init();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Then now you're ready to get your notification

Packages that you need:
firebase_core: ^2.7.0
firebase_messaging: ^14.2.5

### Don't Forget to configure your app with your firebase

Docs
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/